# Number Theory from Polish maths olympiad

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Because the date of sending tasks from this stage has ended I need to know answer of it. This is from the first stage of the [Polish Maths Olympiad](https://om.mimuw.edu.pl/static/app_main/problems/om72_1.pdf) (task 11):

> Let $p$ be a prime number. A natural number $n \in\mathbb N^+$ is **beautiful** only when the sum of the remainders of $n,\ n^2,\ n^3,\ n^4,\ \ldots,\ n^{p-1}$ after division by $p$ is equal to
> $$\frac12p(p-1).$$
> Show that the number of beautiful numbers in $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots,p-1\}$ is odd (uneven).

I was thinking about it quite a lot and thought maybe using the binominal theorem we can prove it but couldn't end proof ://

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow you. If $n<p$ and the rest of the division of $n$ by$p$ is $p(p-1)/2$ then $n= p(p-1)/2$. Maybe you want to say that the rest of at least one of those divisions is that? And even if it was the case $p(p-1)/2\geq p$ for $p\geq 3$ so it cannot be the rest.

Comment: I don't know any Polish, but I can tell with quite some certainty that the exercise specifies that the *sum* of these remainders should be $\tfrac12p(p-1)$: *"...gdy **suma** reszt z dzielenia $n$, $n^2$, ..."*. I've taken the liberty to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** If $n$ is beautiful then so is $n^{-1}$, the inverse of $n$ mod $p$.

If you are still stuck with this idea, feel free to ask for more details. Or click the spoiler below for the full idea of the proof:

> This means beautiful numbers come in pairs, except those for which $n\equiv n^{-1}\pmod{p}$. Show that there is precisely one beautiful number $n$ such that $n\equiv n^{-1}\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Now I see we come from $1\equiv n^{p-1}\pmod{p}$ and then after dividing by n we come to $n\equiv n^{p-2}\pmod{p}$. Am i right ?

Comment: No. The former holds for all $n$, the latter does not. I've rephrased to make the idea clearer.